# Something functioning as "did Init"?? [objective-c]

Tags: objective-c

Guys, what is function called after my class loaded, where i can call "self" there.

thanks advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything that's automatically called *after* init is called. If you want something like that and you're subclassing NSObject, simply override -init and call a method yourself (although, if you're doing that, you may as well do whatever you want to do in init itself).

If you're subclassing something else, look in that class' docs — there may well be something that fits your needs. For example, NSManagedObject has awakeFromInsert/Fetch, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question which of the following you need:

- when your class is linked, the `+load` method will be called
- the first time your class is used, the `+initialize` method will be called

You can override either of those methods. If you do, take care to ensure that the class you are loading or initializing *is* the one you intend; otherwise if someone creates a subclass and does not override the method yours may be called twice with [unpredictable results](http://iamleeg.blogspot.com/2009/07/kvo-and-initialize.html).

It is always possible to use `self` in any Objective-C method. It is just an implicit argument to the method, nothing special.